# style certain divs of parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target specific divs in my markup to hide them using CSS. The two divs I am targeting are within a div labelled "row-20". The 2 divs are named back-button-block, and forward-button-block. I'm using the following CSS, but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.row-20 > .back-button-block, .row-20 > .forward-button-block,  { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="row-20">
                          <!-- Back Button -->
                          <div class="back-button-block">
                             Back
                          </div>
                          <!-- Back button ends -->
                              <!-- forward Button -->
                          <div class="forward-button-block swiper-button-disabled">
                            Forward
                          </div>
                          <!-- Forward button ends -->
                          <h1 class="question">NEXT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The **entire problem** is you have an extra comma after `.forward-button-block` - remove that comma, and it all works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma that's killing your selector.

```css
.row-20 > .back-button-block,
.row-20 > .forward-button-block
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-20">
  <!-- Back Button -->
  <div class="back-button-block">
    Back
  </div>
  <!-- Back button ends -->
  <!-- forward Button -->
  <div class="forward-button-block swiper-button-disabled">
    Forward
  </div>
  <!-- Forward button ends -->
  <h1 class="question">NEXT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Boo.  You should vote to close as a typo, this hardly warrants an answer.  **I did NOT downvote**

Comment: @cale_b - I did